# JSON.stringify () error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var number = 0618260587

JSON.stringify(number)
```

the stringified result is 618260587 , the first zero is automatically truncated.

I tried the following fix

```
if(number.length<8)
        {
        var book1 = "0" + number;
        alert(book1);
```

but it alerts undefined.  I am not sure

1) Why the stringified data truncates the first zero
2) I thought javascript adds two variables irrespective of type

Answer (score 5):

Leading zeroes are a display thing, and not normally part of numbers. There's an infinite number of invisible zeroes before/after every number, but they're not normally shown. If you want the leading zero, treat the number as a string:

```
var number = '0618260587';
```

As well, in most, numbers with a leading zero are treated as octal, not decimal. Bare leading zeroes can cause hard-to-track bugs because of this - it looks like a decimal to you, but it's some completely different number to the interpreters, eg..

```
0618260587 octal = 1616431 decimal
```

Comment: +1 for the warning about octals. In his case (at least on Firefox), it actually works as a decimal, because he has the digit 8. If you changed 8 to 6, it will become octal. Is this fallback to decimal in the presence of invalid octal digits spec'd somewhere?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !! I would have done it , but I require the input to be a number and then stringify it . What is wrong with the fix I tried making?

Comment: @alex: you're not using `number`in your fix. `book` is undefined, making the whole result undefined.

Comment: MarcB , apologies , I had changed the variable while putting the question up , I left that change , The problem still remains

Comment: if `number` is still an int, then it has no `.length`. You have to convert it to a string first. That means your `if()` is failing, since a number can never have a length, so it's doing `if (undefined < 8)`.